# Was Elsie's attraction to Clementine meant to go anywhere?

Tags: westworld-tv

In the first season of the Westworld TV show, Elsie (the behavioural technician) has an intimate moment with the host Clementine. It's very brief as she brushes Clementine's hair aside and kisses her.

And then it's never heard or seen of again.

I'm not sure what the point of that scene was. Was there a storyline that got deleted? Is it meant to give us some clues to her inner nature?

> <sub>As an aside, I'm disappointed in Elsie's character arc. She basically gets written out of the show and nobody seems to care.</sub>

Comment: I might be able to give a partial answer, but it may require second season episode spoilers...and I don't know the code for spoiler tags...

Comment: @DarthLocke I'd love to know how you have Season 2 spoilers (but not interested in what they are), but if it's as-yet unexplained by the show then I guess that's OK to. [Spoiler tags are >!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/131874)

Comment: Thanks for the code!! I went about it with links instead. And the only reason I would consider discussing this as a spoiler, is because it relates to a future of character that may return--not so much that it has been officially confirmed. However there are some rather minimal season 2 spoilers out there in terms of new casting information, other parks, and of course the fun season 2 teaser trailer! I work for free on a spoiler site, we collect spoilers, so I usually know whats up! :D

Answer (score 5):

Let me just say there is heavy **speculation** based on an **easter egg** that Elsie Hugh's story line may not be finished and therefor her nature may still yet be furthered revealed to the audience.

Here are two links one about another character in relation to Elise and the other about the easter egg specifically:

**Vanityfair - S2 Spoilers about Stubbs + tidbit about Elsie:**
https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/05/westworld-season-2-stubbs-alive-dead-luke-hemsworth

**Easter Egg - Code - Analysis:**
https://www.inverse.com/article/24717-westworld-elsie-hughes-alive-the-adversary-stubbs-bicameral-mind-sector-20

**Westworld Wiki:**
Even her statis on the Westworld Wiki is listed as "unknown":
http://westworld.wikia.com/wiki/Elsie_Hughes

It may also be worth noting that when hosts need repairing, they sometimes need re-sculpting and/or rebuilt and that opens the door on the possibility that in theory, there could be more than one of any given host/android.

---

**UPDATE:** Confirmation on Statis of Returning Characters.

**Warning Season 2 Spoilers Ahead!!**

> **Elsie Hughes** (Shannon Woodward) and Ashley Stubbs (Luke Hemsworth):
>  Smart-ass programmer Hughes vanished near the end of season 1, while
>  wary security chief Stubbs was captured by a tribe of Native American
>  hosts when he went looking for her. **Both are alive**, but not exactly
>  doing so hot. “They’re finally getting to experience Westworld as
>  guests and not in the managerial halls, but I’m not sure they’re
>  enjoying their experience,” Joy says dryly. 
>  
>  [EW - Spoilers: Returning Characters for Season 2](http://ew.com/tv/2018/02/28/westworld-season-2-characters/)